# SASS or SCSS use of ampersand

Tags: sass

How can I do this with SASS/SCSS?

sass:

```
.orange
  color: $orange
  button&
    background: $orange
    color: black
```

It should produce the following css:

```
.orange {
  color: #ffa500;
}

button.orange {
  background: $orange;
  color: black;
}
```

I can do it by using `&` as a variable but it requires `@at-root` and it's not really readable/nice:

```
.orange:
  @at root
    button#{&}
      color: white
```

When used alone, the `&` selector works great, but but seems the language doesn't allow tho use it the way I want. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`"&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.`

[DOCS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector)

But you can give your button a class and put it after the `&`

[DEMO](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/807a6472634d51d0b5725771bb95e04d)

```
$orange: orange

.orange
  color: $orange
  &.button
    background: $orange
    color: black
```

Comment: Thanks, but it adds a class and I want to avoid adding classes to keep my html readable, especially when the classes are there to workaround a language flaw :-/. `<button class="button">` is just redundant, and useless outside of the context of fixing this language issue.

Comment: There are naming conventions that would disagree with you, [BEM](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) is 1 example, but you can write code however you see fit. Regardless, I spent the time to answer your question; `you can't do that`. It'd be cool if you accepted the answer.

Comment: BEM philosophy indeed adds classes to provide semantic value. `button.button` to hack the language shortcomings doesn't fall in this category. So far I prefer the solution I suggested, thanks for your time.